# how can i restrict a person from entering a particular username in username field?

Tags: php, if-statement

I want to block a certain word from being entered in my username field.

```
    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);
        
        
        $param_username = trim($_POST["username"]);
        
     
        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
            /* store result */
            mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
            
            **if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1) {
                *$username_err = "This username is already taken.";*
            } else{
                $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
            }**
```

I want to add another condition where I want to block a specific username and show an echo for it.

```
        } else{
            echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
        }
```

Comment: `if ($param_username == "bad-username") { echo "Something went wrong"; }`

Comment: What does it have to do with the mysqli code you showed us?

Comment: because it is somehow colliding with my username fields basically i am creating a login system

Comment: i just want to restrict my name "saurishmonga" from being entered and processed into my database and people should get an echo for that

Comment: you can simply check `if($username!='saurishmonga'){//do stuff}`

Comment: @saurishmonga you want to use a hardcode value, or you want to first check it from db to throw the error.

Comment: @MUFAzmi i just want it to show an error when someone writes "saurishmonga" and submits the form and i am unable to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to compare more than one value.

Try this code.

```
<?php
$reservedUsername = array('saurishmonga','users','friends','settings','logout','blahblah'));

$param_username = trim($_POST["username"]);
if (!in_array(strtolower($param_username), strtolower($reservedUsername))
{
    // insert user in the darabase
    if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)) {

        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);            
    
        if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
            // store result
            mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
            
            if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1) {
                $username_err = "This username is already taken.";*
            }
            else{
                $username = $param_username;
            }
        }
        else{
            echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
        }
    }
}
    else {
        echo "You can't use a reserved username";
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just compare.

```
$forbidden_name = "NameYouWantToCheck";

$param_username = trim($_POST["username"]);
if (strtoupper($param_username) !== strtoupper($forbidden_name)) {

    // insert user in the darabase
    if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)) {

        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);            
    
        if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
            // store result
            mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
            
            if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1) {
                $username_err = "This username is already taken.";*
            }
            else{
                $username = $param_username;
            }
        }
        else{
            echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
        }
    }
}
else {
    echo "$forbidden_name is not allowed!";
}
```

The strtoupper function make both names uppercase before the compare.

Comment: what should i place in between the code to insert in database?